# How to give service account storage.buckets.create permission in GCP Cloud Storage?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the code below to create a bucket, but an exception is occurring indicating that the service account lacks the permission `storage.buckets.create`.

I made the service account a member of the `Storage Object Admin` role, but that was insufficient, as the error still occurs.

```cs
var client = StorageClient.Create();            
var bucket = client.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you view the assigned permissions for `Storage Object Admin`, you'll see that it lacks the permission `storage.bucket.create`

```
'IAM & Admin' > 'Roles' > 'Storage Object Admin'
```

If you view the assigned permissions for `Storage Admin`, you'll see that it **has** the permission `storage.bucket.create` (in addition to other permissions your service account may or may not need).

```
'IAM & Admin' > 'Roles' > 'Storage Admin'
```

**You could create a custom role that had the minimum set of necessary permissions, and apply that role to your service account, or you could make the service account a member of the 'Storage Admin' role. The former would be more preferable in my opinion due to the smaller permissions footprint.**